# Gsub to extract relevant content between two lines

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I want to extract the content between Preparation and Nutrition\nPer serving.
I am using -

```
gsub(".*\nPreparation\n\\s*|Tips & Notes*", "", filename)
```

My filename looks like

```
    \nPreparation\nThinly slice both lemons and one orange. Combine the 
    sliced fruit with rum in a bowl. Cover and let macerate at least 8 hours 
or overnight.\nCombine sugar and water in a small saucepan; bring to a boil. Remove from the heat and stir in tea; let steep for 20 to 30 minutes. Strain into the rum mixture. Cover and chill.\nJust before serving, slice the remaining orange. Strain the rum mixture into a large punch bowl. Add Champagne or sparkling wine and seltzer. Float the orange slices in the punch.\nTips & Notes\nMake Ahead Tip: Prepare through Step 2. Cover and refrigerate for up to 3 days.\nNutrition\nPer serving
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract contents, it's better to use `str_extract` or `regmatches` function.

```
> regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?s)Preparation\\s*\\K.*?(?=\\s*\\bNutrition\\nPer serving)", x, perl=T))[[1]]
[1] "Thinly slice both lemons and one orange. Combine the \n        sliced fruit with rum in a bowl. Cover and let macerate at least 8 hours \n    or overnight.\nCombine sugar and water in a small saucepan; bring to a boil. Remove from the heat and stir in tea; let steep for 20 to 30 minutes. Strain into the rum mixture. Cover and chill.\nJust before serving, slice the remaining orange. Strain the rum mixture into a large punch bowl. Add Champagne or sparkling wine and seltzer. Float the orange slices in the punch.\nTips & Notes\nMake Ahead Tip: Prepare through Step 2. Cover and refrigerate for up to 3 days."
```

Comment: Hey Avinash Can you share a link from where I can study about Regex